# running multiple simulation in ns2 with shell script

Tags: shell, simulation, ns2

I am using the following script using the setdest utility in ns2 to generate multiple scenarios but the script is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

dest_dir="movement"

if [ -d $dest_dir ]
then
      # Do nothing
      echo "'$dest_dir' is a directory"
else
      echo "Creating directory $dest_dir";
      mkdir --verbose $dest_dir
fi

setdest_loc="/home1/ns/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/setdest";

if [ -x $setdest_loc ]
then
      # Do nothing
      echo "$setdest_loc is executable"
else
      echo "$setdest_loc does not exist or is not executable";
      exit;
fi

# Create the scenarios

for i in 0 10 20 40 100
do
      $setdest_loc -v 1 -n 25 -p $i -M 20 -t 100 -x 500 -y 500 > $dest_dir/scen-25-$i
done

echo ""
echo "Created the following files"
echo ""
ls -la $dest_dir/scen-25*
```

it just echoes the if condition setdest is not executable

we use setdest in this way

`./setdest` in the directory of setdest ,so why this is not working how can I write ./setdest in this shell script .?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of your script to see what your script is actually doing. Post the results here if you want more advice

Answer (score 0):

Do an

```
ls -l /home1/ns/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/setdest
```

Does the output show that the script is executable, like

```
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 umair Administrators 238 Aug 11 09:40 setdest
 #--^--^--^
```

At least one 'x' must be set for the script to have any chance of executing.

If not, then you need to change the permissions

```
 chmod 755 /home1/ns/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/indep-utils/cmu-scen-gen/setdest/setdest
```

If this does not answer your question, edit your question to include the output of the `ls -l ...` command specified above.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.